# PHP Can't compare a CAPTCHA string with the user typed in string

Tags: php, html, string, captcha

I created a login system, and also a CAPTCHA string that will generate random characters and will create a string of the form `A1B2C3`, both uppercase and lowercase letters. That's the code:

```
$cArr1 = array_merge(range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"));
$cArr2 = range("1", "9");
$captcha = $cArr1[rand(0, 51)].$cArr2[rand(0,8)].$cArr1[rand(0, 51)].$cArr2[rand(0,8)].$cArr1[rand(0, 51)];
```

That's the form fragment that implies the CAPTCHA:

```
<?php echo "<legend>Please type in the following CAPTCHA: <b>".$captcha."</b></legend>";  ?><div style="margin-top: 5px;"></div>
<input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="A1B2C3" class="textbox" required><div style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Register" class="btn">
```

For example, for the generated value of: `A3z5Q7`, the output will be:

> Please type in the following CAPTCHA: A3z5Q7
>   
> //textbox//
>   //button//

That's how I get the CAPTCHA input:

```
$captchaA = $_POST['captcha'];
```

The problem is, the comparation 
`if (strval($captchaA) == $captcha)`
doesn't work, and it always goes on the `else` statement, returning `Wrong captcha.`

The login form works perfectly without the CAPTCHA, that's why I decided not to provide other parts of the code like `$user = $_POST['user'];`, etc.

I also decided to use `strval()` in the comparation, because I saw that `$captchaA()` is a mixed variable, while `$captcha` is considered a string. At least, that's what VSCode told me.

Any advice? If you need more details, please use the comment section and I'll provide it to you as soon as  possible. Thank you!

Comment: How do you store the generated captcha value for comparison with the user inputted captcha?

Comment: @Alastair what do you mean through "store"? It is stored in `$captcha`

Comment: You generate a captcha and send it to the user, when they POST the captcha back, what do you compare it with? How do you get that original captcha for comparison?

Comment: The original captcha is stored in the variable `$captcha`. You can see it in the first code sequence. After that, a form is shown to the user, involving 3 textboxes: `username`, `pass` and `captcha`. Also, `$captcha` is shown to the users, and he has to type in the value of `captcha`, that is stored through POST in `$captchaA`. The two strings are, then, compared

Comment: @Alastair there are two variables, `$captcha` and `$captchaA`

Comment: Are you sure it's stored? How does it persist? Are you sure you're not generating a new one and comparing against that?

Comment: @Alastair I'm pretty sure it is stored. I can echo `$captcha` anytime, and it is also echoed in the form.

Comment: @Alastair maybe there's some character that was added while concatenating the strings?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible, that's not how PHP works. Try echoing both when you do the comparison. I think they will be different. The captcha isn't stored anywhere, you are just generating a new one before you try to compare it with the original.

Comment: @Alastair oh, man, yes, they are, indeed, different

Comment: @Alastair by clicking the `submit` button, the first captcha is automatically changed, and it is compared to the captcha the user typed in

Comment: You will need to store the original captcha somewhere, e.g. as a session variable or in a database. Once the form is generated then the captcha is lost, so you will need to retrieve it from somewhere when you handle the POST.

Comment: @Alastair I did it! Stored the generated CAPTCHA in a `$_SESSION['captcha']` variable. Thank you so much! You literally saved my code :)) I was about to delete all the verification part

Comment: @Alastair Is there any way I can mark your comment as a solution?

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help. I will write up as an answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not persist variables across requests - the problem is that after the form is generated, the original captcha is lost. When handling the `POST` a new captcha is generated, which is why it will never match what the user has submitted.

The solution is to persist the original captcha (e.g. in the session) so it can be later retrieved for the comparison.